# Where to store the username and password?

Tags: html, asp.net, web

Okay I have created a simple website in ASP.NET website
I wrote a html code for login in Default.aspx
When I run the it was showing the login page
Now how to evaluate the login (where to store the username and password) so that the authenticated user can be logged in

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Could you please give us more information? What are you doing in the POST event, how do you store your values, ...

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store user name and password in DATABASE by creating table e.g. tblUser with columns UserName and UserPwd. The in .cs file write script to connect your application with your database and then pass your UserName textbox's data and password textbox's data to that table in database. I hope you know well about connecting asp.net app to database + CRUD in sql.

SQL Tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp
Connecting asp.net to database:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178371(v=vs.100).ASPX